# Java algorithm for finding minimum weight of heaviest bag

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a set number of items and bags, find the **minimum weight of the heaviest** bag if each item has to be added **consecutively**.

Example:

- Number of bags: 3
- Number of items: 9
- Weight of each item sequentially:
  10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

Hence:

- The first bag will contain items 1 to 5, with weights totaling to 150. 
  (10 + 20 .. + 50)
- The second bag will contain items 6 to 7, with weights totaling to 130. 
  (60 + 70)
- The third bag will contain items 8 to 9, with weights totaling to 170. 
  (80 + 90)

Hence the minimum weight of the heaviest bag will be bag 3 with a weight of 170, notice each item is added consecutively i.e. bag 1 will not contain item 1 and 4 but skip 2 and 3.

My algorithm:

```
public class Packing {
    private void run() {

      //take in necessary input.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int items = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        int luggage = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);

      //parse each item's weight into an array.
        int[] weight = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

      //get total weight of all items.
        long sum = Arrays.stream(weight).sum();

      //new array to hold weight of each bag.
        int[] container = new int[luggage];

        int j = 0;

      //for each remaining item, check if current bag's weight is larger then
      the average weight of the remaining item vs remaining bags. else, increment
      the bag counter and put the next item in the new bag.

        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {

            long avg = sum/(luggage - j);

            if (container[j] < avg) {
                container[j] += weight[i];
            } else {
                if(j < luggage - 1){
                    j++;
                }
                container[j] += weight[i];
            }
            sum = sum - weight[i];
        }
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(container).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
        sc.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Packing newPacking = new Packing();
        newPacking.run();
    }
}
```

For example, the average weight at the start is `450/3 = 150`. 
The current bag has no items, and the first item is of weight 10. Since `10 < 150`, add this item to the first bag.

The weighted average now is:

```
450 - 10 / 3 (remaining bags). = 146.67..
```

This goes on until adding the current item results in the current bag being over the average. The current item then goes to the next bag, the average is recalculated to `(remaining weight)/(remaining bags)`, where the bags remaining  is `3 - 1 = 2`.

This algorithm works okay for my first test case, however it fails for the rest: here's an example of one other test case.

- Number of bags: 3
- Number of items: 10
- Weight of each item sequentially:
  722 94 195 78 649 833 705 941 766 958

Answer should be: `2479, (833+705+941)` but I get `2665`.

Is there a proper algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: It is unclear, what you mean by "each item has to be added sequentially". Does this mean that one bag can only contain consecutive items?

Comment: Yes, ill edit the question